# return result from REGEXP and UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have 2 tables, one named `pictures` and another named `media`.

In table `pictures`, I have the field `description` which contains some text.  In table `media`, there is the row `url` that I would like to update.

I need to write an SQL query that updates row `url` in table `media` that uses regex for an specific string in `description` from table `pictures`.

I was recommened the mysql function `REGEXP` but was told that it cannot return the result.  The problem is that in the field `description` there is an string that I need to `UPDATE` `url` with.

Should I do SQL queries or use a PHP script to update the table?

Comment: MySQL's `REGEXP` only returns `true` or `false`, so unless you can try using some [`SUBSTRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) magic, the best way would be to use PHP.

Comment: There's also https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp but I can't actually verify its efficacy having never used it to my recollection