# apphending the where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have the following code to return the string that i want

```
$sql = "
    SELECT `description` 
    FROM `auctions` 
    WHERE `description` REGEXP '[0-9]{10}'
";
```

however I need to run an update query for something like this

```
UPDATE `url` 
FROM `auctions_media`
WHERE `url` = "$sql" AND `auction_id` = SomeNumber
```

how do i match the tables so that the `auction_id` for `auctions` table matches the `auction_id` in `auctions_media` table??

I want the code to go through all the rows, return the string from description, then use that for the update query

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MySQL subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html). And your [UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) is wrong.

If I understood you correctly, then you need something like this (example of subquery use):

```
UPDATE `auctions_media` 
SET url = 'to something you fetched before'
WHERE `auction_id` = (SELECT id
                      FROM `auctions` 
                      WHERE `some condition you need`)
```

Comment: This will work only if the subquery returns one result.  You may want to use `= ANY` or `IN` for multiple results (or else use the multiple-table `UPDATE` syntax and perform a `JOIN`).

Comment: @eggyal, I know, but I really don't understand what he actually wants. I presented subquery with with statement, which should return 1 record, because I kinda understand him that he goes over loop and updates. Nevertheless, he has links to subquery syntax, and if he want's to learn, he will open that, and read something...

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're after either, but perhaps it's this:

```sql
UPDATE auctions_media JOIN auctions USING (auction_id)
SET    auctions_media.url = auctions.description
WHERE  auctions.description REGEXP '[0-9]{10}'
```

Or this:

```sql
UPDATE auctions
  JOIN auctions_media
    ON auctions_media.auction_id = auctions.auction_id
   AND auctions_media.url        = auctions.description
SET    ...
WHERE  auctions.description REGEXP '[0-9]{10}'
```

Comment: hello again! I have an problem which i posted about here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407304/return-result-from-regexp-and-update, I need to return an section of the string from `description` and use that to update `url`, the 2 columns are in different tables however

Comment: Perhaps some concrete examples would help?

Comment: i linked it here, this is an example of what my table looks like, i need to get the string from `description` then append that to the end of `url` i need to do this now for all the rows http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13583

Comment: @user1989379: As others have explained in comments to [another of your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14407304), it's not possible to do this using MySQL's `REGEXP` operator.  You will either need to parse your `description` fields in a stored program, or else use [a UDF that can return the patterns matched by a regular expression](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/index.php#PREG_CAPTURE_SECTION).

Comment: i have added an new question in observance to this, how do i parse the description field so that each description is correctly tied to the auction_id using php? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444662/php-to-update-sql-from-2-different-tables